# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for yt module

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, yt

I am trying to understand the issue that I am having, but I cannot fully get why I am getting these errors, especially since this error states what I think is a false positive. I know that it has something to do with the line: `for file in glob.glob('puredef_hdf5_chk_000000')`but I am unsure what it might be.

```
import yt
import glob

for file in glob.glob('puredef_hdf5_chk_000000')
ds=yt.load(file)

#########################################
slc= yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,'theta','density')
slc= yt.SlicePlot(0.25,p_size=15.0,col="Pink")
slc.set_cmap('density',('Blues'))
slc.annotate_particles(0.25,p_size=12.0,col='Red')
slc.save('tr')
#########################################
# This
#slc = yt.SlicePlot(ds,"theta", ["density"])
#slc.set_cmap("density","Blues")
#slc.annotate_particles(0.25, p_size=12.0, col="Red")
#slc.save('tr')
##########################################
p = yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,"theta","density",center='m',width=(10, 'Mpc'))
p.annotate_particles((10,'Mpc'))
p.save('tr')
############################################################
#p = yt.ParticlePlot(ds, 'particle_position_x', 'particle_position_y', 'particle_dens')
#or
#p = yt.ParticlePlot(ds, 'particle_position_cylindrical_radius', 'particle_position_cylindrical_theta', 'particle_dens')
# Above is for axi-symmetric
#p.set_ylim(-2.5e10,3.5e10)
#p.set_xlim(1e10,3.5e10)
#p.set_zlim('particle_dens', 1e1, 1e13)    #fixed the density axis
#p.save()
######################################################
#ad = ds.all_data()
#print(ad['particle_position_y'])
######################################################

runfile('C:/Users/rocke/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/home/richard/new 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/rocke/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/home/richard')
  File "C:\Users\rocke\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\richard\new 1.py", line 4
    for file in glob.glob('puredef_hdf5_chk_000000')
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing colon at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `:`

```
for file in glob.glob('placeholder'): # Make sure you add the ':'
    ... # And indent
```

Also, the contents inside a `for` loop needs to be indented one tab

Try this:

```
import yt
import glob

for file in glob.glob('puredef_hdf5_chk_000000')
    ds=yt.load(file)
    
    #########################################
    slc= yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,'theta','density')
    slc= yt.SlicePlot(0.25,p_size=15.0,col="Pink")
    slc.set_cmap('density',('Blues'))
    slc.annotate_particles(0.25,p_size=12.0,col='Red')
    slc.save('tr')
    #########################################
    # This
    #slc = yt.SlicePlot(ds,"theta", ["density"])
    #slc.set_cmap("density","Blues")
    #slc.annotate_particles(0.25, p_size=12.0, col="Red")
    #slc.save('tr')
    ##########################################
    p = yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,"theta","density",center='m',width=(10, 'Mpc'))
    p.annotate_particles((10,'Mpc'))
    p.save('tr')
    ############################################################
    #p = yt.ParticlePlot(ds, 'particle_position_x', 'particle_position_y', 'particle_dens')
    #or
    #p = yt.ParticlePlot(ds, 'particle_position_cylindrical_radius', 'particle_position_cylindrical_theta', 'particle_dens')
    # Above is for axi-symmetric
    #p.set_ylim(-2.5e10,3.5e10)
    #p.set_xlim(1e10,3.5e10)
    #p.set_zlim('particle_dens', 1e1, 1e13)    #fixed the density axis
    #p.save()
    ######################################################
    #ad = ds.all_data()
    #print(ad['particle_position_y'])
    ######################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yt : [WARNING  ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,912 Extending theta dimension to 2PI + left edge.
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,927 Parameters: current_time              = 0.0
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,928 Parameters: domain_dimensions         = [2 2 0]
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,929 Parameters: domain_left_edge          = [ 0.0000e+00 -6.5536e+09  0.0000e+00]
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,931 Parameters: domain_right_edge         = [6.55360000e+09 6.55360000e+09 6.28318531e+00]
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,932 Parameters: cosmological_simulation   = 0.0
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,939 Allocating for 8.800e+01 particles (index particle type 'all')
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-11 16:27:32,941 Identified 9.000e+00 octs
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\rocke\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\richard\new 1.py", line 8, in <module>
    slc= yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,'theta','density')

  File "C:\Users\rocke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\visualization\plot_window.py", line 1464, in __init__
    validate_mesh_fields(test_data_source, fields)

  File "C:\Users\rocke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\visualization\plot_window.py", line 132, in validate_mesh_fields
    canonical_fields = data_source._determine_fields(fields)

  File "C:\Users\rocke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\data_objects\data_containers.py", line 1165, in _determine_fields
    finfo = self.ds._get_field_info("unknown", fname)

  File "C:\Users\rocke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\data_objects\static_output.py", line 798, in _get_field_info
    raise YTFieldNotFound((ftype, fname), self)

YTFieldNotFound: Could not find field '('all', 'density')' in puredef_hdf5_chk_000000.
```

It seems I get new errors doing it your way, but it is reading my data files now. I have not seen this error before, as it is exclusive to the yt module.